# Cannot install libxml2 on python - Linux/Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, libxml2

I am new to python and am trying to use the libxml2 package.
This is what I get:

```
Executed command:
pip install libxml2-python

Error occurred:
Non-zero exit code (1)

Command output:

Collecting libxml2-python

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libxml2-python
```

I am using Kali Linux amd_64, although I have tried on Windows 7 64 and get the same error. I've tried 32 and 64 bit versions of Python 2.7, 3.5.3, 3.6. I am using PyCharm. I have added it to the requirements.txt, tried to add it from there, as well as in both venv and non-venv with different python versions.
I've tried installing it locally, I've tried pip install and easy install, as well as `pip install ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/python/libxml2-python-2.6.9.tar.gz`

I also installed Anaconda, thinking that would sort it, as it comes with libxml2 pre-installed. When I try to import it in anaconda, I get:

```
Executed command:
Conda /root/anaconda3/bin/conda install -p /root/anaconda3 libxml2-python==2.6.21 -y

Error occurred:
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels:

Command output:
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - libxml2-python ==2.6.21

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda libxml2-python

You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with

    conda install anaconda-client
```

The anaconda client is installed.
Also:

```
conda install -p /root/anaconda3 libxml2 -yFetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /root/anaconda3:
#
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0
```

Any suggestions are welcome, please help!